# How to show view controller in UITableViewCell with UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, uicollectionviewcell

i have UITableViewCell with `tableView` and i need show new controller if user select in my cell. But, `navigationController` and `UIStoryboard` doesn't work! How i can do this?

Comment: your question is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to ask is after u tap a UITableViewCell , a new UIViewController would be pushed in. For that, you need to first embed in a navigationController to create a stack of the pushed view controllers. Then, inside tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: add this :

```
    YourController *yourController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([YourControllerStoryboardId class])];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourController animated:YES];
```

Check if you have set the delegate of your UITableView. Clean and Run your code.